# When hyperlink in specific cell clicked, then record that cell address as a last action log

Tags: excel, vba

im very new in VBA, and i gonna appreciate who ever wanting to help me...
Here i have a case, i have several conversation action that linked with Hyperlink.
lets say conversation module placed in cell Q6-Z6, and every cell has a title as a code (p1-p9) which placed on cel Q5-Z5..
i want to make, if that hyperlink clicked (Q6-Z6), then will print title code as a last action log(p1-p9) in targeted cell.

Here i attach a picture that explain what i want..

Thanks for helping

[Picture Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZFoU.jpg)

Comment: Do the hyperlinks already work and cause an action of some sort, like opening a web page or selecting a worksheet? Or can any potential solution to your question replace the existing hyperlinks with new ones that will help produce the result you are after?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ExcelHero: yes.. the hyperlink will open webpage.... so actually that hyperlink clicked and go to send chat via whatsApp API...